# Website can't recognize credential that was saved in Smartlock

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords, credential-manager

Did setup for Smartlock for share credentials betweeen website and mobile app according to https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites
Seems setup works fine (see Case 1). But as I understood it also should work in another direction too (see Case 2)

Case 1 - OK

1. login on the web
2. saved credentials in Smartlock
3. open mobile app and Smartlock was prompted credentials that was
   saved on the web

Case 2 - NOT OK

1. login on the mobile app
2. saved credentials in Smartlock (ensured that credentials was
   appeared in chrome://settings/passwords)
3. try to login with credentials that was entered in mobile app but
   website does not prompt it. But credentials that was entered on
   website are prompted on the website.

I'm not sure but seems there is some issue on the website.
Unfortunately, I can't have access to the website code.

Also I have checked NYT mobile app and website and there same issue. Maybe google documentation wrong and (Case 2) is OK.

I appreciate any help

Comment: can you please check my question? I am facing issue with smart Lock.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830860/app-and-website-saved-password-is-not-sync

Answer (score 0):

The reason the issue was missing SHA fingerprint in firebase console for the App. So after adding it CASE 2 start working fine.

Comment: I am facing some issue in password sync. can you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830860/app-and-website-saved-password-is-not-sync